# Different notion of the topic about continuity and oscillation

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Define osc (or oscillation) to be: $$osc(f,x_{0}) = sup(f,x_{0})-inf(f,x_{0})$$
I would like to show that $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$ if and only if $\underset{[x_{0} - \epsilon,  x_{0} + \epsilon]}{osc}f \rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon$ decreases to $0$.

How do I approach this statement? I am quite new to analysis so any input will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitions doesn't make sense...

You can define the supremum and infimum of a set, but how should $(f,x_0)$ be a set? And how is $\underset{[x_{0} - \epsilon,  x_{0} + \epsilon]}{osc}f$ defined? I suppose it could be
$$
\underset{[x_{0} - \epsilon,  x_{0} + \epsilon]}{osc}f = \sup f([x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon])-\inf f([x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon]).
$$
In that case, your statement is easy to proof.

**Hint:** Define  $$F(s)=\underset{[x_{0} - s,  x_{0} + s]}{osc}f.$$
Then you have to prove: $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $F$ is continuous at $0$.

If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, you can show that for each $\epsilon>0$ exists $\delta>0$ such that $F(\delta)<2\epsilon$.

In Detail:

> Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, for each $\epsilon>0$ exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ with $|x_0-x|<\delta$ holds $|f(x_0)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.For each $x,y\in[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$ holds $|x_0-x|<\delta$ and $|x_0-y|<\delta$ and $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(x_0)|+|f(x_0)-f(y)|<2\epsilon.$$ We observe \begin{align}\left|F(\delta)\right| &= \left|\sup f([x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta])-\inf f([x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta])\right|\\&=\left|\sup\{f(x)-f(y)~:~x,y\in[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]\}\right|\\&=\sup\{\underbrace{|f(x)-f(y)|}_{<2\epsilon}~:~x,y\in[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]\}\\&<2\epsilon\end{align}Next, we see $F(s)\leq F(t)$ for $s\leq t$. Finally we get $$|F(s)|\leq |F(\delta)|<2\epsilon$$for all $|s|<\delta$, which proves the continuity of $F$ at $0$.

If $F$ is continuous at $0$, you have to use
$$
|f(x_0)-f(x)|\leq F(\epsilon)
$$
for all $x\in [x_{0} - \epsilon,  x_{0} + \epsilon]$.

In Detail:

> Consider a sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $x_n\to x_0$. Using $x_n\in[x_0-|x_0-x_n|,x_0+|x_0-x_n|]$ and the continuity of $F$ at $0$, we get $$0\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(x_0)-f(x_n)|\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}F(|x_0-x_n|)=0,$$which proves the continuity of $f$ at $x_0$.

Comment: do you know which textbook that has this sort of problems so I can practice more on my own? Thanks!

Comment: No, I don't know. I never heard of this oscillation before. I just did the proof out of my mind. :-)

Comment: This is the first time I have heard of this terminology. Thanks there!

Comment: Hi, is F(s) continuous at s or 0?

Comment: $F$ is continuous at $0$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.